# Cloning Old Record Versions for a Parent Lookup

Tags: trigger, before-trigger

Composer__c object has a lookup relationship to the Song__c object.
Song__c has a lookup relationship to the Song_Usage__c object.
Song_Usage__c has a lookup relationship to the Event__c object.

Since a Composer record can be associated with multiple Songs records, the requirement is as follows..

If Composer information is updated by the user, and because a Composer record can be associated with more than one Song, my requirement is to NOT let the update reflect on Composer info for Event(s) with the status 'Transmitted'.

My approach so far has been an attempt to clone old Composer versions in a before update trigger and associated them with Song Usage records for Events with the aforementioned status.

My code below:

```
trigger ChangeHandler on Composer__c (before update) {
    Set<Id> usagesIds = new Set<Id>();
    Map<Id, Song_Usage__c> songUsages = new Map<Id, Song_Usage__c> ([SELECT Id, Track__c FROM Song_Usage__c WHERE Event__r.Status__c = 'Transmitted' AND Track__c != null]);
    for(Song_Usage__c su : songUsages.values()){
        usagesIds.add(su.Track__c);
    }
    Map<Id, Track__c> tracks = new Map<Id, Track__c>([SELECT Id FROM Track__c WHERE Id IN :usagesIds]);

    for(Track__c tr : tracks.values()){
        for(Composer__c c : Trigger.old){
            if(c.Track__c == tr.Id){
                Composer__c clone = c.clone(false, true, true, false);
                clone.Track__c = tr.Id;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Looking for ideas please.

Comment: The event object has multiple "song usage" records related, which are related to songs, which are related to composers. So how exactly the composer information for events is changed? What is this information? You mean that an event with the status of "Transmitted" cannot have composers removed or added, being that this information is retrieved by the song usage?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: It really depends on what you are trying to accomplish. For example, I see no problem on saving the song list on a field on the event record when its status is changed to "Transmitted". That field wouldn't change when the record is updated. Another option would be to flag the song usage records when the event status is changed to "Transmitted", so you can create new song usage records without that flag, after the event is transmitted, or something like that...

Comment: If you need this for a report, you might even consider using a separate object to "freeze" the song list when the event is transmitted. Then you can change the song usage records freely, because that information os frozen on another object related to the event. Said object would contain information about the composer stored in non-forumla fields.